# C# nullable types - common pattern

Tags: c#, nullable

Often when using nullable types I get following pattern inside my code (test for value, call a function):

```
Type? a; 

if(a.HasValue)
{
    SomeFunction(a.Value);
}
```

Is there some clever shorthand for this? Does this pattern have a name? Perhaps this question is misguided and I should be using nullables differently...

Comment: The only thing you want it's to call `SomeFunction` just when a is `not null`?

Comment: `.HasValue` and using `!= null` should both be fine in that instance, and they're generally pretty widely used for nullable types.

Comment: Exactly. Most often is something like whenever actual numerical value is provided something should happen and otherwise I'd like the program to proceed (and hope it gets the value later)

Comment: Essentially, something like `a?.SomeMemberOfA()`, but for non-members? Other than writing an extension method to call every possible value of SomeFunction (yeah, no), not really. You could write some weird extension `public static void IfCall<T>(this Nullable<T> x, Action<T> a) where T : struct
        {
            if (x.HasValue)
                a(x.Value);
        }`, but I don't think that would improve anybody's code.

Comment: I would probably move the null check into the SomeFunction. That way it's only in one place and you know that SomeFunction now handles the null parameter value. That's assuming you have access to SomeFunction and can change it.

Comment: Something to do that job might be nice. I can't guess if it'd meet the threshold of usefulness/implementability/harmlessness to qualify for being added to the language, but [see if it's been suggested](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang), and suggest it if not. A few years ago I asked on another SO site about a hypothetical C# feature. Everybody told me my idea was either pointless or dumb and crazy, and then a year later it was implemented in C#7 (on somebody else's suggestion) as `if (x is SomeType st) {...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The null conditional can do this, but to make it work you'll want to make SomeFunction an extension method of Type

```
public static void SomeFunction(this Type? a)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

then you can do

```
Type? a;
a?.SomeFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF/UWP, we often have to deal with adding change notification to every single property. This code is repeating and verbose. People did learn tricks to absract this. Often storing the actuall value in some kind of String Key collection. Wich then takes care of any change notification.

A simple way would (as others have said) be to use Expansion methods with the null-conditional operatiors. Wich of coruse might become quite tedious quickly.

Maybe you could make something similar to the TryParse pattern? It gives you your normal parsing results via a out parameter, and the return value tells if the parsing failed or not. Except in this case, you hand in the function to be called as a delegate and would get the return if it failed due to null values?

The Static and thus non-overrideable [Equals Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_System_Object_), calls the instance (and thus overrideable) one after doing null checks. But in this case, null is a valid input for both values.

But in all cases you still need a way to tell that the operation failed due to a null. So you will not really get around checking something.

Answer (score 0):

If `SomeFunction` takes `Type` you're need to pass `a.Value`, no shortcuts here.

BTW. If you have an aversion to `a.HasValue` then `if(p != null)` is another option.

```
void SomeFuntion(int i) {Console.WriteLine(i);}

int? p = null;
if(p != null) SomeFuntion(p.Value);
```